# net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.clobimpl cannot be cast to java.lang.string(jTDS)

Tags: casting, jtds

`useBlobs=false` using XAPoolDataSource.

Throws an exception like 'title description while call resultset.getObject()'

I don`t know what the issue is.

Comment: I have solved this issue.

Comment: add useLOBs=false after the connection string and use it as first property.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, it's fine on Stackoverflow to answer your own questions.

Comment: you get help from my solution?

Comment: Not me, but other people will. Remember to mark it as the accepted answer too. It keeps the 'Unanswered Questions' queue down and you get reputation points for it.

Comment: Thanks for you advice

Comment: Related, if you see `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl.free(ClobImpl.java:219)` in your stack trace, you're hitting a known issue (https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/771/) worked-around by the solution of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Common Connection String**

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ServerName;DatabaseName=xxx;instance=xxx

**Rule from official site**

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

**My Solution to solve exception as title mentioned**

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ServerName;`useLOBs=false;`DatabaseName=xxx;instance=xxx

**please put `useLOBs=false;` as first param**